# Cell Broadcasting in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, broadcasting

Does iOS 5 onwards support Cell Broadcast messaging, and can we access the messages?

We want our application to receive messages through Cell Broadcast technology, so we need to be able to read those (alerts, small text messages, sometimes images) and show them when the iPhone device is in its Idle state.

Are there any existing Apple frameworks or APIs to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The Official API does not allow you to access any privacy sensitive information, like mail from the mail app, SMS, MSS or Cell Broadcast messages.

There is no way to acces these kind of data with the officially SDK.

Comment: Thanks. Please provide additional info if any on this. Are there any private APIs todo these and made it work, though I know Apple will reject the app.

Comment: Sorry no, since I only develop AppStore apps, I've never needed to use any private API calls.